# Are there downsides to importing both a namespace and a child module? E.g. `import React, { Component } from ...`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I was working with some coworkers on a React component, and I had imported React and started to write my class as

```
import React from 'react'

Class MyComponent extends React.Component
```

when they suggested I import Component as well, i.e.:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

This is a new pattern to me, and my first reaction was to guess that importing both the namespace and a child module would cause them to be double-imported, as we'd have both a `React` object and a `Component` object (which also exists under `React`).

My second reaction was to think that since objects are passed by reference, both `React.Component` and `Component` would reference the same object in memory, so the only real difference is that there'd be an extra (but minimal -- not counting the other modules under React) `React` object.

However, I'm not sure. Which is correct? Or is neither?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the module won't be double-imported. There isn't much difference really between this two ways of importing. The second way makes sense if you have many components in a file, so you can write just `extends Component` instead of `extends React.Component`.

In this case,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

is essentially the same as

```
import React from 'react';
const { Component } = React;
```